# FS write JSON in a specific manner

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fs

I want to use FS to write files in this format, how would I acieve this with FS. I have tried using `FS.writefiel` but that just replaces the other content and I have tried using `FS.appendfile` but it doesn't write the files within the [ ] and VS code states there is an error.

```
[
{
"part1": "yes",
"finish": "no"
},{
"part2": "yes",
"finish": "yes"
}
]
```

Comment: You could try if https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-pretty-compact or similar packages meet your requirements.

Comment: How would I accomplish this with the package?

Comment: What is the issue, where are you stuck ?

Comment: I want to use FS to write files in that format but the methods I used `writefile` and `appendfile` don't write files in that format, I need it in that specific way for a bot.

Comment: What, in that specific format? Or just JSON?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Tadman I want the data to be written within the [ ] and then within the { }

Comment: That's just regular JSON, nothing special. It's an array of JSON objects.

Comment: Ik, I want to use FS to write an array of JSON objects, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

```
var array = []

data = {
    "part1": "yes",
    "finish": "no"
}

data1 = {
    "part2": "yes",
"finish": "yes"
}

array.push(data)
array.push(data1)

array.toString()
const stringArray = JSON.stringify(array)
fs.writeFileSync('array.txt',stringArray)
```

You can do something like this.

1. First create an array.
2. Then push your objects into that array.
3. Then convert array to a String by using **.toString()** method
4. After that use **JSON.stringify()** method to convert entire thing to string.
5. Then use fs.writeFileSync() method to write it into the text file.

**Solution 2 :**

1. First create a file called array.txt in your fill structure.
2. Then add two empty square brackets inside the array.txt file ([]).
3. After that run the below code.

You can change the data(JSON Object) values as you wish.

```
const fs = require('fs')

var newArray = []

const readFile = fs.readFileSync('array.txt')
const array = JSON.parse(readFile)

data = {
    "part1": "yes",
    "finish": "no"
}

if(array.length == 0) {
    newArray.push(data)
    newArray.toString()
    const stringArray = JSON.stringify(newArray)
    fs.writeFileSync('array.txt',stringArray)
} else {
    const arrays = fs.readFileSync('array.txt')
    const ar = JSON.parse(arrays)
    ar.push(data)
    const newData = JSON.stringify(ar)
    fs.writeFileSync('array.txt',newData)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to write the file without overrideing the previous one?

Comment: I came up with a another solution but here first you have to create a empty file call array.txt and you have to create empty array inside the array.txt file I'll edit my previous answer with the new solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all just regular JSON, which it appears to be:

```js
let data = [
  {
    part1: "yes",
    finish: "no"
  },{
    part2: "yes",
   finish: "yes"
  }
];

fs.writeFileSync('output.json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I want to be able to use it again, to add the next one also within the [ ].

Comment: You can always rewind the file enough to skip past the ending `]`, then write in a new record.

Comment: It honestly sounds like what you want is [ndjson](http://ndjson.org) or line-delimited JSON. This is *super* easy to append to, you just write another line.

Comment: How would I do this? NDJSON or rewind the file

Comment: NDJSON is less messy. Rewinding and rewriting might work if you *must* have JSON.